# how to create a dynamic redirect link with js and php?

Tags: javascript, php, post, header

PHP has no relation and behavior with browsers and in some times it makes some mistake. For example we can't set for header function to redirect to a page in a blank page. Because it has no relation with the browsers and for doing this, we should use JS .Now I'm mixing these two languages to reaching the goal.

```
 <?php
     $word = $_POST["tagTxt"];
     $tag = "https://www.example.com/" . $word;

     echo '<script>window.open("Location: <?php $search;?>");</script>';
?>
```

The goal is this code but it doesn't work. I want get a string from a first page then post it with post method and then past it to a static address for redirecting with blank target. Thanks.

Comment: you can use : header("location:".$search); it ill redirect from php direct, but dont echo or make any space or html code before the php tag.

side note : php has relation with the browser it exchanges things with it like cookies and headers

Comment: @AmrMagdy Thank you for answering. In this respect, PHP has relation. but the things that I said is another. Dear Your opinion certainly is correct but I want to do that in a new blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to open a new url when the page is loaded.

So if you trying to do this check the code below. 
This way you are mixing the parameters received from client, processing them and them sending back to the client.

Then you use the javascript with the window.onload function to execute the redirect page when the page is loaded with the received parameter.

```
<?php
$word = "1";
$tag = "www.yahoo.com/" . $word;

echo '<script text="text/javascript">window.onload =     function(){window.open("'.$tag.'");} </script>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood your question, but have you tried something like this:

```
<?php header("Location: $search");
```

Comment: Yes. It was the first way that I checked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are "changing" the web page. Do not use `window.open`

Use `window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';`

in your example do this

```
 <?php
   $word = $_POST["tagTxt"];
   $tag = "https://www.example.com/" . $word;

   echo "<script>window.location = '$tag';</script>";
?>
```

(copy the code above, and it should work perfectly for what you're asking for)

Answer (score 0):

I fount the way.
thanks all.

```
<?php
   $word = $_POST["tagTxt"];
   $tag = "https://www.example.com/" . $word;
   echo "<script>window.open( '$tag' );</script>";
?>
```